# Julia: hangs trying to convert PyObject set to Vector

Tags: type-conversion, julia, sympy

I am using Julia v 0.3.10 with Juno. I am trying to extract the symbols present in a SymPy symbolic expression, but the program hangs on me.

The following lines execute without error:

```
Pkg.add("SymPy")                   (Ok)
using SymPy                        (Ok)
x, y, z = Sym("x", "y", "z")       x,y,z) 
ex = x + 2y + 10z                  x + 2*y + 10z)
symb = free_symbols(ex)            PyObject set([x, y, z])
vekt = convert(Vector{Sym}, symb)  Vector Sym,3
```

The following hangs the program, the "working" icon in the lower left shows up and never disappears.

```
vekt[1]
```

Why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong, if so, what? Is this a bug in Julia, if so: will it be fixed and is there a workaround?

Please help!

Comment: Does `Set{Sym}(symb)` help?

Comment: It converts to a Set{Sym} without error. Thank you, this might be something I can work with!

Comment: This got answered on GitHub: `collect(symb)`. The change got checked into the master branch of SymPy already, so you can just do `free_symbols(ex)` going forward.